# Xcode 11 pin menu for Auto Layout is missing (under Main.storyboard) - only on this project

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, watch, auto

Xcode 11 is missing the Pin menu for Auto sizing on the lower right of the screen - same line as the device emulator name display.

Recent backups have the same problem. Backup from two weeks ago, for this project, show the Pin menu for Auto layout, but prefer not to go that far back.

I looked at the Main.layout file in the text editor saw nothing interesting, but I have no knowledge what it should look like,

I Used Terminal command: spctl --assess --verbose /Applications/Xcode.app

It shows I have a valid version of Xcode.

Stackoverflow has answers on this problem from several versions ago, that do not work with current xcode 11.2.1.

It is a Swift, iPhone + Apple Watch project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: Check the box for "Use Auto Layout" in the file inspector. 1) Click on the Main.storyboard., 1) Right-click on the Main.storyboard. 2) Click on "Show File Inspector" This may or may not show you the "Interface Builder Document". It should bring up your right Pane if it was closed. 3) Click on one of the controls on your story board, this should bring up the "Use Auto Layout" if it was not already displayed. 4) Check the "Use Auto Layout". You should now have your Pin Auto Layout buttons.